# Take additional field value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
Select 
    p.Id, p.Nazwa 
From 
    tbProjekt p                     
Where 
    EXISTS (select UP.* 
            from tbUserProject UP               
            where UP.ProjectId = p.Id And UP.UserId = 1)
```

I want to select the additional column `UP.IsFullAccessso` so change the first line to this one:

```
Select 
    p.Id, p.Nazwa, UP.IsFullAccess
```

but I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier "UP.IsFullAccess" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to tbUserProject in your main query then:

```
Select p.Id, p.Nazwa, UP.IsFullAccess  
From tbProjekt p
INNER JOIN tbUserProject UP          
  ON p.Id = UP.ProjectId
WHERE UP.UserId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

UP exists only within the EXISTS sub-query and can't be accessed from the main query.  You may be able to use a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    p.Id, 
    p.Nazwa,
    UP.IsFullAccess 
FROM tbProjekt p                       
JOIN tbUserProject UP              
   ON UP.ProjectId = p.Id 
   AND UP.UserId = 1
```

The main difference is the possibility of duplicates if you have more than one matching record in the `tbUserProject` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique values from tbProject and there is many values in tbUserProject for one project and one user use this:

```
SELECT
    p.Id, 
    p.Nazwa,
    UP.IsFullAccess 
FROM tbProjekt p                       
INNER JOIN 
(
    select ProjectId, MAX(IsFullAccess) as IsFullAccess  from tbUserProject UP where UP.UserId = 1
    group by ProjectId

) UP ON UP.ProjectId = p.Id
```